# GridView - add formatted child rows from Ajax call that matches the rendered grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms, ajax.net

I have an asp.net webforms site with a rather large GridView. The GridView is rendered from a filtered list of data objects.

Some of the data objects have children of the same type.

In my GridView, I'm initially only showing the parent objects. I want to be able to expand the parent to show the child objects, via an Ajax call, and insert the new rows under the parent.

The catch is, they need to follow the same formatting and rendering rules as the parent, and fit in with all the rest of the existing rows. This means that all columns of the new child needs to fit in the columns of the rest of the rendered grid.

I would also like to re-use the existing GridView rendering methods if possible, so I don't have to maintain duplicate code that essentially does the same thing.

I can easily use the DynamicPopulateExtender from the AjaxControlToolkit to call a web service to get the child rows, but that wouldn't easily give me the rendered and formatted HTML that would fit into the already rendered GridView table.

Is there a way to get this to work properly, or is there a different way I should approach this?

Comment: An alternative (and probably simpler method) is to place the grid inside of an update panel and do your rendering in the codebehind to give it an ajaxy feel.  Just remember to call the update panel's update method when you are done.

Comment: @Jeremy That's actually what we're doing now, which I want to move away from, because of the shear size of the GridView. I would like to not have to re-render the entire GridView when we just want to show Child objects.

Comment: Fair enough.  You guys do any paging on your grid?

Comment: Unfortunately no and I'm not going to be able to change this right now because of business rules.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Ajax calls and insert the data with jQuery perhaps using a templating engine like [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) to merge the data. Use the same css classes for the gridview and template to keep the uniform look you want.